# Android Studio design view not loading

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

I've been using android studio for a while now and I have never had any problems. Today i tried to open a new project and the Mainactivity file opens  but when i try to open the design view (as shown in the picture) it just keeps loading and never stops. I tried closing and reopening android studio but it still loads without finishing. Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

[android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZ0O0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below methods and let me know:

First, let the studio build the project completely. Preview won't be available until the project is built. Make sure you've correct library implementation in Gradle and you have a stable internet connection. If those are okay then follow the below methods-

1. Invalidate Cache and Restart Android Studio
2. Restart Your Computer
3. Create a new project and try building it.

Let me know if it fixes your problem.

[image: Screenshot of Invalidate Cache Option]

Comment: I managed to do it, thank you for your help!!

Comment: Share your steps solving the issue.